# Thermodynamics- $PVT$ adiabatic system

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-diagram

1. In thermodynamics, what is a phase?
2. Imagine a container full of air where the walls of this container are adiabatic and there is a piston on the top of it. If we push the piston downwards, the pressure increases while the volumes decreases. But what happens to temperature? If we're transferring energy as work, this energy would increase the kinetic energy of air particles, so the temperature would increase. So, the pressure and volume aren't inversely proportional, right? One increase, and the other increase, but we can't forget that temperature changes.
   Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you are asking in (1).

(2) During adiabatic compression, the temperature of the system does change.  Starting from the first law of thermodynamics:

$$\mathrm{d}U = \mathrm{d}Q + \mathrm{d}W$$

For an adiabatic process $\mathrm{d}Q=0$. If we assume an **ideal gas**, then the internal energy is $\mathrm{d}U = C_V\, \mathrm{d}T$ and the work is $\mathrm{d}W = -P\, \mathrm{d}V = -\frac{NkT}{V}\mathrm{d}V$.  So

$$ C_V \frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} = -Nk \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}.$$

For an ideal gas $C_P = C_V+Nk$, and both of the heat capacities are independent of temperature. It is also common to define the adiabatic index $\gamma = C_P/C_V$.  After some algebraic manipulation the differential equation can be rewritten:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{T} = (1-\gamma)\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}.$$

Integrating, while remembering to include a constant of integration, gives:

$$ T\, V^{\gamma-1} = \mathrm{constant}.$$

Using the ideal gas law, we can substitute for $T$:

$$ P\, V^\gamma = \mathrm{another\,constant}.$$

Pressure is not inversely proportional to volume for an adiabatic compression.  They are related by a power law that depends on the adiabatic index.

Answer (score 0):

In thermo*statics* a phase is a region of space occupied by a homogeneous material characterized by a pair of thermic and caloric equations, i.e., $T=f(V, x_1, x_2, ...) $ and $U=g(V, x_1, x_2, ...) $, resp., where $V, x_1, x_2, ...$ are the various extensive variables describing the mechanical, chemical, electrical, magnetic, etc., configuration. Different phases have different function pairs $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$: same material, say $H_2O$, but with different functions for  temperature and internal energy that are the dependent variables of the independent configuration variables. The thermic and caloric functions can also be described with intensive variables as independent parameters or with a mixture of extensive and intensive, as well.